# Robocopy, starts, then stops

Tags: windows-7, crash, robocopy

Hey I know robocopy is capable of bypassing the whole 260 character path limit in windows, so I was going to use it, but I came to a slight problem.

When I launched it, the CMD for it pops up for about half a second, and then closes itself, this happens on my Windows 7 netbook, which I use since my Vista desktop is, well, only half usable at the moment.

Any ideas as to why this could be happening, I'm running in admin so I know that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `/V` switch to enable verbose output and try `/LOG:file` . This could produce some information on what's going on.  You say it's closing, are you opening a batch file? If so try running the command inside the prompt manually so it stays open.

Comment: To be honest, I'm opening start, typing robocopy and pressing enter.

Comment: @user88311 it's a command line tool, not a GUI

Comment: Well aware of that, if you open the start menu in windows seven though and type robocopy it opens the cmd with it preloaded, mind you I solved the problem by simply starting cmd first then running the robocopy cmd, also on a side note micrsoft released a gui for robocopy.

Comment: No, it does not open Cmd.exe and then start Robocopy, it simply runs Robocopy.exe directly. You should be aware that that's how all command-line programs work in Windows, and unless they pause their output the window will simply close.